# Facing errors while running VHDL code using EDA playground

Tags: vhdl, edaplayground

I'm trying to run the following VHDL code using EDA playground as no VHDL simulator is installed on my Laptop. The upper part is the source code and lower part is the testbench. However, getting some errors which need to be resolved. The errors are given below. Is there anyone can help to sort out the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity led_controller is
    Port (  clk, reset: in std_logic;                    
            in_word: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   
            LEDs: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end led_controller;

architecture behavior of led_controller is
    --------------------- signals ---------------------
    type freq is array (0 to 3) of integer range 0 to 50000;
    signal frq: freq := (25000, 10000, 5000, 2500);      
    signal led_freq_count: integer range 0 to 50000 := frq(0);

    type d is array (0 to 3) of integer range 0 to 100;
    signal duty: d := (10, 30, 60, 85);      
    signal duty_cycle: integer range 0 to 100 := duty(0);        
    signal LED_switch, new_command: std_logic := '0';
begin

    --------- clock process / sync reset configuration ---------------
    process (clk)
        variable duty_counter: integer range 0 to 100 := 100;
        variable freq_counter: integer range 0 to 50000 := led_freq_count;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            ------- if reset was high or new in_word were arrived --------

            if reset = '1' or new_command = '1' then
                LEDs <= "0000";
                duty_counter := 100;
                freq_counter := led_freq_count;
                new_command <= '0';
            else  
            ------- blinking process --------

                if freq_counter = 0 then 
                   freq_counter := led_freq_count;
                   LED_switch <= not LED_switch;
                else
                freq_counter := freq_counter - 1;
                end if;

                if duty_counter = 0 then 
                   duty_counter := 100;
                else
                duty_counter := duty_counter - 1;
                end if;
                ------ output assignment -------
                if LED_switch = '1' and duty_counter < duty_cycle then
                    LEDs <= "1111";
                else 
                    LEDs <= "0000";
                end if;
            end if;
        end if; 
    end process;

    --------- input process---------------
    process (in_word)
    begin
        case in_word(3 downto 0) is
            when "0001" =>   led_freq_count <= frq(0);
            when "0010" =>   led_freq_count <= frq(1);
            when "0100" =>   led_freq_count <= frq(2);
            when "1000" =>   led_freq_count <= frq(3);
            when others =>   led_freq_count <= frq(0);
        end case;
        case in_word(7 downto 4) is
            when "0001" =>   duty_cycle <= duty(0);
            when "0010" =>   duty_cycle <= duty(1);
            when "0100" =>   duty_cycle <= duty(2);
            when "1000" =>   duty_cycle <= duty(3);
            when others =>   duty_cycle <= duty(0);
        end case; 
        new_command    <= '1';
    end process;


end behavior;
```

testbench.vhd:

```
initial begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
  $dumpvars;
  #10000 $finish;
end

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity main_testbench is
end main_testbench;

architecture behavior of main_testbench is
    component led_controller is 
        Port (  clk, reset: in std_logic;                   -- system clock is assumed 10KHz 
                in_word: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   -- LS 4 bits - frequency & MS 4 bits - duty-cycle   
                LEDs: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));    
    end component;

    signal clk, reset:  std_logic := '0';
    signal in_word:     std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00010001"; -- 0.2 Hz, 10% duty cycle
    signal LEDs:        std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";

    type in_word_commands is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal in_words: in_word_commands := ("00010001", "00010010", "00010100", "00011000", -- 10% duty cycle with 0.2Hz, 0.5Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz
                                          "00100001", "00100010", "00100100", "00101000", -- 30% duty cycle with 0.2Hz, 0.5Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz
                                          "01000001", "01000010", "01000100", "01001000", -- 60% duty cycle with 0.2Hz, 0.5Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz 
                                          "10000001", "10000010", "10000100", "10001000"); -- 85% duty cycle with 0.2Hz, 0.5Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz
    signal command_num : integer := 0;

begin
    dut: led_controller port map (clk, reset, in_word, LEDs);

    clk <= not clk after 50 us; -- 0.1ms/2 = 50us  
    command_num <= 0 after 5000 ms when command_num = in_words'HIGH else command_num + 1 after 5000 ms;
    in_word <= in_words(command_num); 
end behavior;
```

> [2018-05-13 10:40:56 EDT] vlib work && vcom '-2008' design.vhd testbench.vhd  && vsim -c -do "vsim testbench; vcd file dump.vcd; vcd
>   add -r sim:/testbench/*; run 80000 ms; exit"
>   VSIMSA: Configuration file changed: `/home/runner/library.cfg`
>   ALIB: Library `work`attached.   work = /home/runner/work/work.lib
>   Aldec, Inc. VHDL Compiler, build 2014.06.88
>   VLM Initialized with path: "/home/runner/library.cfg".
>   DAGGEN WARNING DAGGEN_0523: "The source is compiled without the -dbg switch. Line breakpoints and assertion debug will not be available."
>   COMP96 File: design.vhd 
>   COMP96 Compile Entity "led_controller"
>   COMP96 Compile Architecture "behavior" of Entity "led_controller"
>   COMP96 File: testbench.vhd
>   COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0016: "Design unit declaration expected." "testbench.vhd" 1 1
>   COMP96 Compile Entity "main_testbench"
>   COMP96 Compile Architecture "behavior" of Entity "main_testbench"
>   COMP96 Compile failure 1 Errors 0 Warnings  Analysis time :  40.0 [ms]
>   Exit code expected: 0, received: 1

Comment: If I remove that part then it shows - No *.vcd file found. EPWave will not open. Did you use '$dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;'?

Comment: The problem is solved now. However, don't know why I'm not getting the desired LED output.

Comment: I don't imagine you'll be able to usefully simulate for 80 seconds on EDA Playground. There's [gtkwave](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkwave/files/) and [ghdl](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases).

Comment: (The issue that was solved was having a Verilog snippet in testbench.vhd)

Comment: One of the great things about EDA Playground is that you can easily share code by sharing the unique URL for each playground. That is particularly useful when posting a question of a site lack Stack Overflow, because then everyone else can see what you're seeing. (Though you should also paste the code in the question as you have done.)

Comment: VHDL simulations on EDA Playground automatically produce waveform dumps; Verilog simulations do not. Therefore, you don' need to add any code to VHDL to dump waveforms.